# Set log4j output log file underneath my project Not eclipse

Tags: java, log4j

I use Eclipse as my IDE to develop my project.  The log have been output to myproject/logs/log.log as I expected, until I did some setting that I saw from some web site.

I went to Windows -> preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variable  to add the "log4j-1.2.16.jar".
Since then, the log file started showing under D:\eclipse\logs\ instead of D:\workspace\MyProject\logs.

I have deleted the classpath variable entry and restart Eclipse, but I just cannot have the log file created under my project anymore.

Help!!!
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks both cherouvim and Jens for your replying!

Jen's answer is actually what I am looking for, since my client doesn't necessary use Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

It's best if you explictly define the path where the log should go. For example if this is a webapp deployed on tomcat you can:

```
log4j.appender.YOURLOG.file=${catalina.home}/logs/my-application.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the log file location (if not an absolute path) is relative to the working directory of your app. You can set the working directory of your application in the run configuration:

Run -> Run Configuration -> Arguments Tab

in the lower part of the screen you can set your working directory